# Fluent NHibernate 1.1 with Microsoft Access 2007 Database

Tags: database, nhibernate, ms-access, fluent

Is it possible to use Fluent 1.1 with Access?  I found this site [here](http://www.thoughtproject.com/Snippets/NHibernateWithAccess/) that shows how to create a configuration file that can be passed into `Fluently.Configure(config)`.  The issue with this is that you need to use NHibernate 1.2.1 which Fluent gets upset with because it has a reference to version 2.1.2.4000.  Here is the error:

```
Error   1   Assembly 'FluentNHibernate, Version=1.1.0.685, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8aa435e3cb308880' uses 'NHibernate, Version=2.1.2.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'NHibernate, Version=1.2.1.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' d:\Project\lib\FluentNHibernate.dll Project
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://dixond.blogspot.com/2010/08/nhibernate-and-ms-access-its-simple-but.html) should sort you out.

Alternatively, [try this page](http://blog.yodersolutions.com/2008/12/getting-ms-access-to-work-with-nhibernate/).